# Avoid multiple tick marks in 3D tikz plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code in tikz to generate a 3D-Plot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in,
height=2in,
at={(0.0in,0.0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-1,
xmax=1,
tick align=outside,
xlabel={$x$},
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
ylabel={$y$},
zmin=-1,
zmax=1,
zlabel={$z$},
view={45}{20},
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]

which looks almost as it is supposed to be. However, the tick marks of the plot are not as desired... they should only point into one direction (one single tick mark per tick). At the moment, there are multiple tick marks at each tick.

For example, at the coordinate (x,y,z) = (1,1,1), there are three tick marks, while there should be none, because no number is there. At (x,y,z) = (1,1,-1), there are also three tick marks, but there should be only one...

How can I fix that such that the tick marks look "as expected"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, I checked the manual but could not find any hints. Other answers on this site also don't come up with solutions. It seems that `pgfplots` is not very flexible in this regard. You could first draw the axes without the ticks, and later add them like in the following example.

Note that `clip=false` is needed in order to make the ticks visible outside the plot. Also, you have to adjust the number of ticks manually. :/ Finally, the tick marks overlap the axis … so, in all this is not the best solution. But I put it here since I could not find a better one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in,
height=2in,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1,
xmax=1,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
zmin=-1,
zmax=1,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
zlabel={$z$},
ticklabel shift=5pt,
tick pos=left,
tick style={draw=none},
view={45}{20},
clip=false,
]

\foreach \x in {0,.5,1} {
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[black!25] (xticklabel* cs:\x,0) -- (xticklabel* cs:\x,5pt);}\temp
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[black!25] (yticklabel* cs:\x,0) -- (yticklabel* cs:\x,5pt);}\temp
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[black!25] (zticklabel* cs:\x,0) -- (zticklabel* cs:\x,5pt);}\temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that looks good. Pretty surprised that such a basic functionality has to be done manually.