how can get 3d axis labels in latex tikzpicture?
I am trying to draw the latex picture as same as shown in the given image. Almost all I have done but I am unable to draw the axis label as shown in the image. Please anyone can help me?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={60}{30},
        axis lines=none, % Draw axes lines
        samples=30,
        samples y=10,
        domain=0:360,
        xmax=20,
        ymax=20,
        zmax=20,
        grid=major,
        enlargelimits=true,
        axis on top,
        shader=flat,
        opacity=1.0,
        colormap={gray}{color(0cm)=(lightgray); color(1cm)=(lightgray)},
        xtick=\empty, % Remove x-axis ticks
        ytick=\empty, % Remove y-axis ticks
        ztick=\empty  % Remove z-axis ticks
    ]
        % Upper cone z = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            faceted color=black, % Color of the grid lines
            draw=black, % Draw the edges with black lines
            z buffer=sort,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:10,
        ]
        ({y*cos(x)},{y*sin(x)},{y});
        
        % Lower cone z = -sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            faceted color=black, % Color of the grid lines
            draw=black, % Draw the edges with black lines
            z buffer=sort,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:10,
        ]
        ({y*cos(x)},{y*sin(x)},{-y});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


This is close:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={60}{30},
xmin=-25, xmax=25,
ymin=-25, ymax=25,
zmin=-25, zmax=25,
colormap={gray}{color(0cm)=(lightgray); color(1cm)=(lightgray)},
axis lines*=left,
minor tick num=4,
tick align=outside,
xtick distance=10, ytick distance=10, ztick distance=10,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
draw=black,
z buffer=sort,
domain=0:360, samples=30,
y domain=-20:20, samples y=20,
] ({y*cos(x)},{y*sin(x)},{y});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The tick marks for 3D axis are drawn on two orthogonal planes (only one for the y-axis when using axis lines*=left or similar presumably because of a bug).
I could not make this work:
x tick style={draw=none, insert path={(0,0,0) -- (0cm,-0.3cm,0cm)}},

as the style is not applied the same way as the axis style - see e.g.:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635524/8650
and the coordinate system is not local for the single tick mark and \tick and \ticknum is not available.
The only option left as I see it is to draw the ticks manually - see answer by @Jasper Habicht here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418459/8650
for marks othogonal to axis.
